# Which parameter I should use to check for collision detection

Tags: ros, fcl, collision-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the fcl library to detect collisions between two objects
I used the following code:

```
    bool flag = false ; 
    collisionObject co0(Shpere0, tf0);
    std::vector<CollisionObject*> boxes;
    generateBoxesFromOctomap(boxes, *st_tree);


           for(size_t i = 0; i < boxes.size(); ++i)
           {

               bool res2 = solver.shapeIntersect(*Shpere0, tf0, *boxes[i], tf1, &contact_points, &penetration_depth, &normal);
              static const int num_max_contacts = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
              static const bool enable_contact = true;
              fcl::CollisionResult result;
              fcl::CollisionRequest request(num_max_contacts, enable_contact);
    //       flag = fcl::collide(&co0, &co1, request, result);
    //            OR 
    //       flag = res1 ;

      }
```

Which value is the right one ? I want if flag = true then there is a collision and if flag == false then there is no collision .. so which one is the write one ????

```
    //       flag = fcl::collide(&co0, &co1, request, result);
    //            OR 
    //       flag = res1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203339/which-parameter-i-should-use-to-check-for-collision-detection/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new and I am answering with every doubt, but following [fcl](http://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl):

---

// Given two objects o1 and o2

CollisionObject* o1 = ...

CollisionObject* o2 = ...

// set the collision request structure, here we just use the default setting

CollisionRequest request;

// result will be returned via the collision result structure

CollisionResult result;

// perform collision test

collide(o1, o2, request, result);

By setting the collision request, the user can easily choose whether to return contact information (which is slower) or just return binary collision results (which is faster).

---

I have come to understand that flag is necessary only to validate that collision test was performed successfully. What you are looking for (the outcome of collision) is the **result** variable.

---

Originally posted by [Morgane](https://answers.ros.org/users/21508/morgane/) with karma: 41 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1